# simple search in django not showing the result

Tags: django, search, django-rest-framework

Please any help on why it is not showing the result.

views.py

```
def display_object(request):
    obje= ObjectName.objects.all().order_by('objectName')
    paginator = Paginator(obje, 3)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    obj= paginator.get_page(page)
    query_list = ObjectName.objects.all() 
    query= request.GET.get("q")
    if query:
         query_list= query_list.filter(objectName__icontains = query)

    imp = {
        "Objects":obj,
    }
    return render(request,'Impact/displayObject.html',imp)
```

displayObject.html

```
<form method='GET' action=''>
                <input  name='q' type="text" value='{{ request.GET.q }}'  placeholder="Search..."/>
                <input type="submit" value="search"/>
            </form>
```

output
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOwly.png)

Comment: Where is the result displayed in your template ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your are not applying the filter.

Try this:

```
def display_object(request):
    query= request.GET.get("q")

    obje= ObjectName.objects.order_by('objectName')
    if query:
        obje = obje.filter(objectName__icontains = query)  

    paginator = Paginator(obje, 3)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    obj= paginator.get_page(page)

    imp = {
        "Objects": obj,
    }
    return render(request,'Impact/displayObject.html',imp)
```